# firebase database delete specific data not all data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to delete any data at specific time . Currently, on the client side, I loop through all the data, the problem is it doesn't stick to the specified field, in my case the "endtime". Instead it deletes all data. The data has a field "endtime", which is the metric I want to use to make the deletions.
My data :

```
{
  "Locations" : {
    "-M1-hX8f46ppZmTMNQIk" : {
      "endtime" : "Wed Feb 26 2020 14:33:54 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "starttme" : "Wed Feb 26 2020 12:32:48 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "waringtype" : "تنبيه جوي",
      "weatype" : "رياح"
    },
    "-M1-htZHGAWxYOwzeKPk" : {

      "endtime" : "Wed Feb 26 2020 13:33:54 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "starttme" : "Wed Feb 26 2020 12:32:48 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "time" : "12:58:01 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "waringtype" : "تنبيه جوي",
      "weatype" : "رياح"
    }
  }
}
```

Code :

```
   this.items.subscribe((a:any)=>{
  a.forEach(singlemarker => {

    console.log(singlemarker)

    let ref = this.db.list('/Locations', ref => ref.orderByChild("endtime").equalTo(singlemarker.endtime))
    .snapshotChanges().subscribe(queriedItems => {
      queriedItems.forEach((ele) => {

        let keys = ele.payload.key;

        console.log(keys);

        this.db.list('/Locations/'+keys).remove()
        console.log()

      });
      });
```

How can i  delete each data by their specific end time .Not delete all data ?

Comment: Are you getting the correct data in your `console.log` ?

Comment: Yes i have  correct data in your console.log

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a data on a specific time, then you need to use `equalTo()` instead of `endAt()` and since you are using [angularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md):

```
let ref = this.db.list('/Locations', ref => ref.orderByChild('endtime').equalTo(singlemarker.endtime)).snapshotChanges();
```

This query should return the node that contains `endTime` equal to `singlemarker.endtime`. The above will return an observable, then you can subscribe:

```
ref.subscribe(queriedItems => {
    console.log(queriedItems);
    queriedItems.forEach((ele) => {
      console.log(ele.payload.key);
      let keys = ele.payload.key;
      this.db.object('/Locations/'+keys).remove();
    });
});
```

Use `snapshotChanges()`, which will return a `payload` that contains the `key` and then you can use `object()` to reference the `key` and `remove()` to delete the data.

---

So if `singlemarker.endtime` is equal to `Wed Feb 26 2020 14:33:54 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)`, then the above query will return:

```
   "-M1-hX8f46ppZmTMNQIk" : {
      "endtime" : "Wed Feb 26 2020 14:33:54 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "starttme" : "Wed Feb 26 2020 12:32:48 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)",
      "waringtype" : "تنبيه جوي",
      "weatype" : "رياح"
    },
```

Comment: if i post data , he deleted immediately .he doesn't stick to the specified time

Comment: are u using angularfire?

Comment: because in angularfire, you should do the following `let ref = db.list('/Locations', ref => ref.orderByChild('endTime').equalTo(singlemarker.endtime)).valueChanges()`; then you subscribe `ref.subscribe(queriedItems => {
  console.log(queriedItems);  
});`

Comment: check the answer, is this what you want?

Comment: After you edited your code , he doesn't deleted any data by specified time

Comment: no , still not working , he deleted all data from root , he is not delete key that equal to specific time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code, you are deleting the entire document.
When you run a query, then the ref is the root document upon which you are running the query.
You need to delete the specific doc returned, determined by the document key.

modify your code appropriately according to this sample:

```
firebase.database().ref(snapshot.ref+snapshot.key).remove()
```

Comment: unfortunately  he deleted immediately all data , he doesn't stick to the specified time

Comment: I think the problem is with the line ` this.db.list('/Locations/'+keys).remove()`
This is deleting from root because you are referencing the entire list.

Comment: any new idea how to deal with it

Comment: Yes. If you could figure out how to instantiate a blank reference (Not within a list), then you should be able to dynamically concatenate the individual keys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208607/discussion-between-kisinga-and-ali-ghassan).

Comment: l am sorry , i was far way from pc . can we discussion again pls ?